# [Python]How to automatically assign a special index to the dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the follwoing dataframe:

```
Bank      Date           %     Type
BankA    29/12/2019      1%     A
BankB    20/12/2016      1%     A
BankB    19/12/2016      2%     B
BankA    29/12/2019      1%     B
BankA    29/12/2019      2%     A
```

I want to create a 4 digit number for creating an Index
The logic is that when Bank and Date and % are matched, the 4 digit number will be same as previous.
The Index is created by combining Number and Type

```
Expected output
Number  Bank    Date            %     Type     Index
0001     BankA   29/12/2019      1%     A      0001-A
0002     BankB   20/12/2016      1%     A      0002-A
0003     BankB   19/12/2016      2%     B      0003-B
0001     BankA   29/12/2019      1%     B      0001-B
0004     BankA   29/12/2019      2%     A      0004-A
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "Type " in row 0(A) is different than row 3 (B) but  "Number"  is same? It's ambiguous of your  logic.

Comment: Hi Zhubei, Type dont need to be matched as stated. It is used for append after the number for the index column.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['Number'] = (df.groupby(['Bank','Date','%']).ngroup()+1).astype(str).str.zfill(4)  
df['Index'] = df['Number']+'-'+df['Type']
df

    Bank        Date   % Type Number   Index
0  BankA  29/12/2019  1%    A   0001  0001-A
1  BankB  20/12/2016  1%    A   0004  0004-A
2  BankB  19/12/2016  2%    B   0003  0003-B
3  BankA  29/12/2019  1%    B   0001  0001-B
4  BankA  29/12/2019  2%    A   0002  0002-A
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit on ".ngroup()+1).astype(str).str.zfill(4)" ? I have tried with a larger set of data but the number is not ranking in acceding order

Comment: `ngroup` stands for number of the group (enumerate) and starts with zero thats why +1 is here. After you enumerate your groups use `zfill(4)` which fills your string with zeros as many decimals as you want. It is 4 in your case.

Comment: its ranked by the groupby result

Comment: so should i use len(df) if i have a longer value?

Comment: use len(df) for what?

Comment: if i have a new row, will all the previous assigned number change? Can i fix the number once i assigned?

Comment: using this method they might change if you run the code again